# Change Another Image On Link Hover

Tags: javascript, image, colors, hover

The output in HTML is something like this:

```
ProductImage1             ProductImage2       ProductImage3         ProductImage4
Color1 Color2 Color3                          Color2 Color4         Color5 Color6
```

What I want to do is when I hover my mouse over any color above, an original (current) image of ProductImage will change to another one (to match the hovered color). And that original image will be back when mouse leaves.

Here is the javascript I've done for hovering over each ProductImage.

```
var sourceSwap = function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var newSource = $this.data('alt-src');
    $this.data('alt-src', $this.attr('src'));
    $this.attr('src', newSource);
}
$(function () {
    $('img.main').hover(sourceSwap, sourceSwap);
});
```

**UPDATE**

I excluded unnecessary parts from my question. The answer from @hunter worked very well when I tested it here jsfiddle.net/4dK2x/27. However it didn't work when I combined it with my php parts to create dynamic lists. I'm still looking around and trying to find out the problems. I will come back and update my answer if I find a solution for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's updated code which should work with as many sets of products as you need if you mimic a similar html structure

```
$('.image .toggles img').hover(function () {        
    var src = $(this).attr("src");
    var $main = $(this).closest(".image").find(".main");
    $main.attr("toggle", $main.attr("src")).attr("src", src);
},
function () {        
    var $main = $(this).closest(".image").find(".main");
    $main.attr("src", $main.attr("toggle"));
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/4dK2x/1/

Comment: Hi, I changed your code a little bit here jsfiddle.net/4dK2x/27 and it worked like a charm. However something goes wrong when I applied it into my php structure for dynamic lists. My hover function on the main image itself is working, but the hover function on colors didn't work and a new image didn't show. I used <table> and for/while loops to display the products in row. Did I make something wrong in my scripts posted before? Any ideas please? Thanks

Comment: can you post the html that your PHP code generates and the js you're using?

Comment: Rather than the PHP code can you paste in what the generated HTML looks like?

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. I updated the page. Is my problem because variant $color_palettes[$ii] of for loop does not exist in the main class of <img> tag? I spent hours trying to fix it but it didn't work. :(

Answer (score 0):

You could do this two ways, you can try it by using CSS:

```
#tagName{
background: url("yourImage.jpg");
} 
#tagName:hover{
background: url("anotherImage.jpg");
}
```

this assumes you have a div tag around the image, you can also reference class id's etc. (read into CSS for more details).

or you could do it through JavaScript
lets say you are not using JQuery (i need to familiarize myself more with JQuery)

```
var image1 = document.getElementById("nameofDivTag");

//on hovering kinda forgotten the JS version of hovering, JQuery has probably easier way

image1.style.background("url:("aDifferentImage.jpg"));
```

if i am wrong yay! if not yay!
hope it helps

Comment: Thanks. I think the answer from @hunter would work for my case. I just need a little more help from him to make it work.

Comment: that's no problem, it's actually quite useful for me to learn a different technique too.